# Why doesn't visual studio exit the debugger on application exit?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to figure out what changed within a project that now causes the application to not exit the debugger when I close the application I am debugging. I have also noticed that unhandled exceptions no longer invoke the unhandled exception handler, I am not sure if it's related.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of application is it (web app, sharepoint, desktop application or something else).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The debugger exits when all the threads exit.  You've probably created an extra thread and done nothing to terminate it.

And this would explain unhandled exceptions being uncaught: if they happen on a different thread you won't see them on the main thread.

Answer (score 12):

This is probably due to other threads, which are not set as background threads, keeping the application alive. Background threads will terminate when the application does, whereas foreground threads will keep the rest of the application alive until they complete.

One way to check for the thread(s) that are responsible is in the debugger, as follows:

- Run your app in the debugger
- "Exit" your app.
- Wait until the app should have exited but hasn't
- Break into the app using the "pause" button
- Open the "Threads" debugging window
- Look for any threads in this window. Chances are there will be one, or a few threads showing. See if you can identify what they are by the info in the window.
- It may also help to open the "Stack" debugging window and then double-click on each thread in the "Threads" window in turn and look at the contents of the "Stack" window. You may be able to see what any stuck threads are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Most certainly the application has not actually terminated. Do you have any other threads running? An application will not shut down until all foreground threads have terminated.